# Where can I find raw data of neutron energy spectra?

Tags: nuclear-physics, electrical-resistance, neutrons, data

I am looking for raw data of the (normalized) neutron flux of a $^{241}$Am-$^9$Be-source, or in other words, the data of [this](http://hypernews.slac.stanford.edu/HyperNews/geant4/get/AUX/2016/05/20/08.17-75260-AmBeSpec_ISOrecomm.jpg) graph. Where can I find that? 
Apparently, there has to be an ISO standard.

I know that NIST and NNDC publish a lot of data similar to this, but I couldn't find anything on their pages.

Comment: Do you mean ISO 8529, Reference neutron radiations — Part 1: Characteristics and methods of production?

Comment: yes - I can only find textbooks with paywall

Comment: Welcome to ISO standards (sigh). You may be able to access through a good engineering library (or radiation physics), or through interlibrary loan.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ISO standard (which will be expected in industry and many government contexts), there are the [evaluated nuclear data files](https://www-nds.iaea.org/exfor/endf.htm) (of which there are actually several sets as several countries maintain their own), if you are willing to accept data that has already been processed and harmonized by experts.<sup>1</sup>

The format of the files is a bit painful by modern standard, but if you have processed a lot of data in Fortran 77, you'll be right at home.

---

<sup>1</sup> As opposed to the raw data from individual experiments each with their own systematic and methodological issues. I strongly recommend accepting the processed data. Just once I decided that the data I wanted was obscure and may not have been considered important by the ENDF maintainers and went back to the original sources myself. Waste of three weeks work: my results agreed quite closely with the official results.

Comment: Yes, this would be totally fine for me, in fact I only need a rough estimate. However, I cannot find the $^{241}$Am-$^9$-Be reaction. What do I have to type in?

Comment: The ENDFs are pretty raw, and they may not have exactly the data you are looking for but just the inputs to the problem. You may have to fold the $^9\mathrm{Be}(\alpha,n)$ production data with the Am-241 alpha energy spectrum. You may even have to write a Monte Carlo for the energy loss of the alphas. I was doing Po-210 alphas on C-13 and had to write a full MC, but Am/Be is much more common.

Comment: That said, try Target: `Be-9` Reaction: `He4/n'` Quantity: `sig`.